# CSS 100 percent height body and element

Tags: css

I am having an issue making one of my elements 100% within an overall layout that is 100%.

I have tried different positioning solutions and I either end up with hidden content the floats behind the footer at the bottom, or the content ends up going behind the footer, and carrys on after the footer.

Here is what I have for the page layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">

<head>
<style>
    *{margin:0}
    html,body{margin:0; padding:0; height:100%}
    .wrapper{position:relative; margin:0 auto -200px; height:auto !important; height:100%; min-height:100%}
    .container{width:930px; margin:0 auto; text-align:left}
    .right{float:right; width:680px; background:#FFF; margin:60px 10px 0 0; padding:0}
    .left{float:left; width:240px}
    .content{padding:10px}
    .footer{position:absolute; width:100%}
    .footer,.push{height:200px}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div id="left">
   left
</div>
<div class="right">

<div class="content">
    content
</div>

</div>
<div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    footer
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The layout for the page being 100% height and footer at the bottom works it just the div with the class name content that I would like to be 100% as well and push the footer further down if the content reaches the footer and not disappear.

Any help most appreciated.

http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/7725/screenshotbj.png

Comment: you might have better luck at the sister site http://doctype.com/

Comment: fix your html code to show everything and I'll fix your styling for you

Comment: fixed, sorry about that it was working until you actually post

Comment: +1 for a move http://doctype.com/, if I could vote :)

Comment: I signed up and posted with doctype.com, this is very much like this site. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: doctype.com has now closed down

Answer (score 12):

Answering animuson: actually the following code is necessary for IE6 support:

```
min-height: 100%; /* real browsers */
height: auto !important; /* real browsers */
height: 100%; /* IE6: treated as min-height*/
```

IE6 doesn't understand `!important`, but it does treat height as min-height. So to support both IE6 and modern browser you have to use the exact same code (order is important).

Comment: This worked for me by putting this in my body's css and "height:100%" in the html css.

Answer (score 7):

The correct css should look like this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html,body
    {
        margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;
    }
    .wrapper
    {
        position:relative;
        min-height:100%;
        /*background: #fef;*/
    }
    .container
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 930px;
        padding: 0 0 200px 0; /*200 pixels at the bottom, to stay over the footer*/
        /*background: #fff; */
    }
    .left /* This was one cause. Old line: <div id="left">, new line: <div class="left"> */
    {
        float: left;
        width: 240px;
        /*background: #efe;*/
    }
    .right
    {
        float: left;
        width: 690px; 
        /*background: #efa;*/
    }
    .right .content
    {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .clear
    {
        clear: both;
    }
    .footer
    {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        /*background: #eff;*/
    }
</style>
```

I'm sure this will help you.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
           left
        </div>
        <div class="right">

            <div class="content">
                content
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

This will look like you wanted to have it. The footer is at the bottom, everytime, just as you wanted to have it :)
Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this solution and it gives me the same scenario. My issue isn't with the footer it is with the right column not being 100% height. When I through in positioning into the div it works except the text gets lost behind the footer.

Basically I am trying to get a 100% height element within an element already set 100% - I am thinking this isn't possible as I can not find a solution anywhere unless I go JS - which I am not prepared to do.

Comment: Not prepared as in... you don't know JS or aren't able to use javascript in your solution due to constraints from the boss?

Comment: I did a screen shot on what I get when I use your layout above. http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7949/screenshotoil.png

Comment: Here is something I was toying with and just do not know how to  make it work either, was to make the background container larger and extend to infinity so to speak. Can I get away with that?

As for JS I tried that and I was having issues on the when the browser resized.

I am strickly a PHP programmer and the front guy got fired. Need a job!

Comment: look, ive found something for you :) http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-2-column-left-menu-pixels.htm

Comment: That works if the text in the content area is filled, once empty the height does not do the 100 percent.

Got a web site? I now looking to either try something else or hire some to fix this.

Comment: combine my code, with the other. maybe it could be the solution

Comment: Found it, and it works. The web site you sent me to didn't work, but I did a search based on faux columns, and followed the instructions for a three column 100% header footer. Do I post it here answer my own question? Incase one else needs it.

Answer (score 2):

Without being able to look at the code until a little later, I'd suggust putting the class "clearfix" onto the div that isn't fully expandning with the white.

[Here](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/) is where you can get a good definition of what clearfix is, and a definition for the css.

Comment: Tried the clearfix and it still doesn't drop the right side 100% height of the body.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use javascript (obviously not the cleanest way but in some cases it can be useful).

Using jQuery:

```
//Get height
var divHeight = $('#div').height();

//Apply css rule
$('#anotherDiv').css('height', divHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite late answer, however it might be useful for others.
You can simply use 100vh (vh is viewport-height unit)

Answer (score 0):

In your code footer has position:absolute but the actual position (eg. bottom: 30px;) is not given. Also, if you want the .content or .push to affect the .footer position, they would have to be in the same flow (eg. both position:static;). Giving footer position:absolute by definition takes the footer positioning from the normal flow, so this is incompatible with the objective.

I assume what you're trying to do is get a page that is 100% even with little content, and a footer that's always on the bottom of the page/screen.

FooterStickAlt is a good cross-browser solution to achieve that.
http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/footerStickAlt/

Comment: Yes, I have this using this layout - http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Now I am adding left and right elements which I would like at least the right to be 100% height to carry the white background to the footer. As it is now with content it looks fine, if it has no or little content the white does not carry through.

http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/7725/screenshotbj.png

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution based on a lead that Cen wrote; searched 100% Layout with Faux Columns and got this http://www.savio.no/examples/three-column-layout-6.asp

With a little tweaking and splicing up my layout different I came up with the following solution which works across all browsers.