# auto adjust div height with the content and managing responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, height

I want to adjust the height of a div with it's content. if I use something like `min-height: 100px;` when the screen will be smaller (in a mobile device) the div will be too much big for the screen. How can I do this ?

Any help will be very appreciated.. Thank you

**EDIT :** my content is a `background-image`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height to be 100% instead of a pixel value. There are some nuances with this approach regarding cross-browser support.

This is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989795/1789650) to fix the issues with percent heights.

You can also use responsive styles via media queries on the viewport height and width. This is a [good tutorial](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries) for that as well.

Comment: Thank you :) using the answer of your first link doesn't change anything, (My content is supposed to be a `background-image`)

Answer (score 0):

When coding responsive designs my advice is to try using percentage values, besides meta tags or media queries. For example min-height: 10%;

Answer (score -1):

Try to use viewport meta tag

Read more here -->
[Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score -3):

```
display:block
```

You can apply this style to your 'div'.

Comment: DIV's default display property is block.